# OSError: -2, File "urequests.py", line 76, in request

Tags: micropython, api, pi-pico-w

I am working with Pi Pico W, it is already connected to the Wi-Fi, I can see it in the `ifconfig()` output.

Furthermore, I am using this urequests code from https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/python-ecosys/urequests/urequests.py. When I tried to update the records, I received the following error:

```
This one Going 0113A70CA811 {'27/02/2023': {'clock': '09:26', 'anamolies': 'Lateness', 'machine': 'IT'}}
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function send_data at 0x2000d000>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 104, in send_data
  File "request.py", line 10, in put_request
  File "urequests.py", line 188, in put
  File "urequests.py", line 76, in request
ValueError: Unsupported protocol: mongodb+srv:
```

I tried to **check the Api server/URL** from Postman but its working fine, I **extended timeout** in request by 10 sec, I even **rebooted pi.** Nothing helped.

I don't know what's the cause!

**Update**

So basically I am using almost the same setup and code as https://github.com/sbcshop/Raspberry-Pi-Pico-RFID-Expansion this project. Just I am using RPi Pico W for connection. More, running two threades in main.py, first will read and display the tag, second one will send request. Also I have update extact url below.

One more think to mention, earlier with the same modules and URL I was able to request, was working fine.

request.py

```
import urequests
import json
import MSAL

def put_request(id, json_data): 
    url = 'https://url/app/clock/{}'.format(id)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': '{}'.format(MSAL.get_token())}
    response = urequests.put(url, data=json.dumps(json_data), headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
    response.close()
```

main.py

```
def send_data():
    global data
    print('gonna send req here')
    while True:
        while data:
            d = data.pop(0)
            print('This one Going', list(d.keys())[0], list(d.values())[0])
            request.put_request(list(d.keys())[0], list(d.values())[0])
            print('Left over', data)
            utime.sleep(0.5)
        utime.sleep(1)
```

Line 104 `request.put_request('0113A70CA811', {'24/02/2023':[]})`

Line 10  `response = urequests.put(url, data=json.dumps(json_data), headers=headers)`

Line 188 `def put(url, **kw): return request("PUT", url, **kw)`

Line 76 `ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)`

Comment: This could be a problem related to SSL handshake. Can you post more code? Are you connecting to mongodb, and what is the connection string?

Comment: Hi @GChuf please check updated question.

Comment: OK, more questions - where is the mongoDB an how do you connect to it? Which line is "line 104 in send_data", and which line is "line 10, in put_request"?

Comment: Hi @GChuf I have update the line above, I am connecting to mongoDB via node.js API

Comment: I think this is a problem in node, then. Do you have any errors from your node api?

Comment: @GChuf I dont think because my front hand wensite working fine, even I test on postman was working.

Comment: Maybe you can try decoupling your backend from your frontend. Take a look at this answer if it helps you.
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/unable-to-connect-with-node-js-due-to-mongodb-srv-get-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined-matchesparentdomain/14030/11